# Other users not able to fetch a user's(user A) presence on re-registration of User A once user A is manually deleted via admin interface in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mnesia

We are working on a chat application involving ejabberd server.
I have ejabberd 14.07 installed on my server. I am manually deleting a user from the admin interface. The user gets deleted successfully.
Now when we re-register the user from the client application again, the other contacts are not able to fetch its presence.
Any inputs?

another example

Here's what I'm seeing:

- create a user matt
- create a user fred
- matt asks to subscribe to fred's presence notification
- fred receives subscription request and responds with "subscribed" presence packet.
- remove fred using web admin interface
- create a new user, also called fred
- matt asks to subscribe to fred's presence notification
- fred never receives subscription request
- matt and fred appear in each others' rosters but the subscription type is "none".

When I look (with a binary viewer) in the roster.dcd file in the "spool" directory, I see users in there that I have deleted and who aren't showing in the web admin interface.

Has anybody else experienced this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the intended behaviour:

1. You delete the user: his data are deleted, including contact list (roster).
2. When you recreate it, you need to approve again contact that can see his presence (because contact list was deleted).

For privacy reason, deleting a user obviously need to trigger deletion of his other data.